# SQL query to perform in access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table:

```
purchase_stock_entry(id,purchase_party_id,bill_no,dt,product_id,qty,price,type)
purchase_party_name(purchase_party_id,name_shop)
```

I want output in column as `(bill_no,name_shop,sum(qty*price))` with join of this two table

i am also tries:

```
select p1.bill_no,p2.name_shop,p1.qty*p1.price as [Total],p1.dt from purchase_stock_entry
p1,purchase_party_name p2 where p1.purchase_party_id=p2.id
```

but for the sum how i can??

Comment: And I want a Porsche... What is your question ?

Comment: I want output bill_no,name_shop,sum(qty*price) this column but unique by bill_no

Comment: Some basic formatting would help. Check out  my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447784/splitting-and-exporting-multiple-tables-from-ms-access/19449390#19449390) question as a guide.

Comment: Thanks but in this query i want sum of two column which are multiplay and use to get shop_name from other tables by join, so i am confuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT bill_no, name_shop, SUM(qty * price) AS [total]
FROM purchase_stock_entry INNER JOIN purchase_party_name
  ON purchase_stock_entry.purchase_party_id = purchase_party_name.purchase_party_id
GROUP BY bill_no, name_shop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this, It can be work

SELECT p1.billno, p2.name_shop, sum(p1.price * p1.qty)
FROM purchase_stock_entry p1, purchase_party_name p2
WHERE p1.purchase_party_id = p2.purchase_party_id